# Mesomeric effect in crotonaldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, resonance

I tried making structures using lone pair of oxygen but I am unable to achieve a structure which doesn't violate the octet rule.

[image: crotonaldehyde]

Comment: You should shift the pi elctrons in -C=O on O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, the mesomeric effect is shown by the carbonyl group. It's an electron withdrawing group.

What happens here is that since the oxygen is a highly electronegative atom, it will tend to pull the $\pi$ bond electrons towards itself. Thus, the carbon becomes electron deficient i.e. it has it's electrons drawn towards the oxygen.

So, we can safely say that a $\ce{-C=O}$ i.e. the carbonyl group is an electron withdrawing group. So, it has a -R/-M effect.